# alternativas al if en java

Tags: java

Hola buenas necesito hacer el siguiente codigo

```
#Entrada (numero entero del 1 al 10)
#Salida en texto (se ha introducido el numero cinco
```

Ejemplo

```
#Introduzco el numero 6
#Haz introducido el numero "seis"
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto sin tener que estar haciendo un if o un swuitch  sin tener que estar poniendo todas las posibilidades del 1 al 10?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedes crear una lista con los nombres en texto, de modo que cada uno se corresponda con su índice, y luego usas los índices en tus comparaciones y muestras los textos correspondientes...

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, me puedes dar un ejemplo de como quedaria el codigo?

Comment: `String [] numeros= {"Cero", "Uno", "Dos"};`

Comment: perfecto gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui es ponerse creativo, puedes hacer un ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> nombreNumerosList = new ArrayList<String>();
nombreNumerosList.add("Cero");
nombreNumerosList.add("Uno");
nombreNumerosList.add("Dos");
nombreNumerosList.add("Tres");
nombreNumerosList.add("Cuatro");
nombreNumerosList.add("Cinco");
nombreNumerosList.add("Seis");
nombreNumerosList.add("Siete");
nombreNumerosList.add("Ocho");
nombreNumerosList.add("Nueve");
nombreNumerosList.add("Diez");
```

Despues de que tengas el numero que el usuario digito seria poner la posicion.

```
nombreNumerosList.get(numero);
```

PD: puse el "Cero" para que coinsidiera mas facil el numero pero sino entonces le puede hacer un -1

```
nombreNumerosList.get(numero-1);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos